# Is a deep plate still a plate?

Tags: word-request

Is it still a plate or is there some special word for it? It's just that "on a plate" is more familiar to my ear than "in a plate"

[image]

Comment: That's a bowl, not a plate.  You put food in [inside] a bowl.

Comment: Agree with Billy. Bowls can be shallow or deep, including in geology. But don't forget deep dish pizza.

Comment: A wide, shallow bowl to eat soup from is sometimes called a 'soup plate', but usually if it's deep enough to contain much liquid it's a bowl.

Comment: @KateBunting - Possibly annoying to learners, we serve food **in** a soup plate - "_At a formal dinner, soup is served in a soup plate and the oval soup spoon is the only spoon laid on the table_"

Comment: The picture is of a cereal bowl, which the cultured would never eat soup from ;)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWGne.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bowl.  A "deep plate" is called a bowl. You can put food "in" a bowl.